# Limiting HTTP Listener Active Threads to control number of concurrent mule flow instaces

Tags: mule, mule-component

I am trying to do a test on how to limit the number of concurrent incoming HTTP requests. 
So I tried to simulate the following scenario. 
I have created a simple flow with 
1. Http Listener as Msg source 
2. Using Groovy Script, Sleeping for 15 seconds to introduce delay 
3. Set the Payload with Hello world.

So any single request will have Min 15 sec of response time. Then in order to limit number of active threads (i.e assuming to control concurrent requests / processing threads) , I have set the maxActiveThreads to 1. So ideally I would allow 1 concurrent thread to process the flow.

Now when I fire using apache benchmarking, as simple get with 1 request, I receive with response time as 15 seconds, which is fine. Now when I increase the number of concurrent requests to 2, I still receive the response time as 15 seconds . I am expecting it be 30 seconds

I see the behaviour until 9 concurrent requests. Beyond 9, then from 10th request onwards it is placed in the waiting queue.

So can an expert please explain how Can I limit the number of active threads to 1. And how is the number of concurrent requests set to 9 (I see in threads using `JConsole` there are 9 `SelectorRunner` threads, which I assume there are linked to it).

Below is the simple flow.

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8082" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration">
<http:worker-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="1" />
</http:listener-config>
<flow name="getting-sartedFlow">
<http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP" />
<scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
    <scripting:script engine="Groovy">
        <![CDATA[Thread.currentThread().sleep((long)(15000));]]>
    </scripting:script>
</scripting:component>
<set-payload value="Hello World" doc:name="Set Payload" />
</flow>
```

Comment: I've tried running that app and had no problem testing it manually, I'd get 15 seconds between responses. Could you share the apache benchmark command? Also, the mule version where the app is running. Thanks.

Comment: Here is the ab command, aiming for 9 concurrent threads with 9 total requests . "ab -n 9 -c 9 http://127.0.0.1:8082/" . Mule 3.6 community stanalone server edition on my laptop.

Comment: And also when I have added the Logger as first step to log with the maxActiveThreads as 1 and number of concurrent requests as 2, below is the log where if you see the timestamp, it is logged at the same time, where in Ideally there needs to be 15 secs delay.    "ERROR **2015-03-17 11:16:05,821** [[getting-sarted].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] LOGGING: Hello I am here
ERROR **2015-03-17 11:16:05,822** [[getting-sarted].http.listener(4) SelectorRunner] LOGGING: Hello I am here".

Comment: Thanks, I was now able to test it myself and found the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered in the [forum](http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/limiting-http-listener-active-threads), you need to define a `poolExhaustedAction` for the `worker-threading-profile`. If you don't then the default one will be used which is RUN, which explains the behavior you're seeing. From what I understand you should use WAIT.

`<http:worker-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="1" poolExhaustedAction="WAIT"/>`

Comment: Thanks . It worked. But for benefit of other users, In Anypoint Studio for Http Listener Config wizard, you will find that "WAIT" as default Pool Exhausted Action, which is wrong.  The default is "RUN" as per documentation.

Comment: I raised the issue and it's being fixed. Thanks for bringing it up.